# Find the number of n-digit ternary sequences with no "012" subsequences

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

My colleague challenged me to solve this problem. I approached this by partitioning by the first digit...

Consider the 3 cases for the first digit of the sequence (0, 1, 2). If we have no restrictions, finding the number of ways to create **all** possible n-digit ternary sequences is trivial to express as a recurrence relation:

$0: a_{n-1} \ ways$

$1: a_{n-1} \ ways$

$2: a_{n-1} \ ways$

So the possible ways to form **all** possible n-digit ternary sequences can be expressed as: $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$

---

But if we can't have a "012" subsequence in the n-digit string, then things get a bit harder, but not by much. We can still partition by the first digit. If we have a zero, we may run into the problem where we have a "012" subsequence, but the number of ways for when `1` or `2` is the first digit is the same:

$0: ?$

$1: a_{n-1} \ ways$

$2: a_{n-1} \ ways$

How can we exclude the "012" subsequences? I did this by sub-partitioning when 0 is the first digit. If we have `00` as our **first 2 digits**, then  we won't have the problem where "012" is a subsequence. There are $a_{n-2}$ ways to do this because we've already chosen the first 2 digits. The same applies for `02`; we won't get the problematic sequence (i.e. `012`).

If `01` are our first 2 digits, then we may have a problem. The only possible choices are `010` and `011` - **2 choices**. We decided on the **first 3 digits**, so we have $2a_{n-3}$ ways to choose the remaining digits to form the n-digit string.

Here is my full partition:

$0:$

$ \ \ 00: a_{n-2} ways$

$ \ \ 01: 2a_{n-3} ways$

$ \ \ 02: a_{n-2} ways$

$1: a_{n-1} \ ways$

$2: a_{n-1} \ ways$

By the Addition Principle, I can sum all parts of the partition. This gives me:

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3}$$

or the cleaner:

$$a_n = 2(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3})$$

**Am I correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't quite work. It is not the case that inserting $00$ or $010$ in front of a legal sequence necessarily gives a legal sequence.  A simpler approach might be to note that inserting any digit in front of a legal sequence of length $n-1$ results in a legal sequence of length $n$ unless the inserted digit is $0$ and the sequence began with $12$.  But inserting $12$ in front of a legal sequence of length $n-3$ always produces a legal sequence of length $n-1$, so we know that among the $a_{n-1}$ legal sequences of length $n-1$ there are $a_{n-3}$ that start with $12$.  Therefore
$$
a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-3}.
$$

Comment: `It is not the case that inserting 00 or 010 in front of a legal sequence necessarily gives a legal sequence.` Doesn't it though? If my sequence is legal, prepending those strings is legal.

Comment: I wrote a Python program to verify that my recurrence is incorrect. Mind elaborating on what I'm incorrectly counting?

Comment: If your sequence starts with $12$ then inserting $00$ gives $0012$ and inserting $010$ gives $01012$, both of which contain $012$.  This means you can't say that inserting $00$ gives $a_{n-2}$ sequences or that inserting $010$ gives $a_{n-3}$ sequences.  The rest of your conclusions are correct: inserting $1$ or $2$ in front of a legal sequence does give $2a_{n-1}$ sequences of length $n$; inserting $02$ in front of a legal sequence does give $a_{n-2}$ legal sequences of length $n$; inserting $011$ in front of a legal sequence does give $n-3$ legal sequences of length $n$.

Comment: `12` is in $a_2$ so for $a_4$ you'll count `0012` as being in the case `00`.

Comment: Ah! So it would be better to take all possible sequences $3a_{n-1}$ and subtract out all that start with a `012`? That way, when we recurse, we are guaranteed to never have `012` in the sequence: $\therefore 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-3}$?